Raspberry pi 4 as SDIO Slave with ch32v307
How can Raspberry pi 4 be used as an SDIO slave device. I need to transfer data from a ch32v307 chip (which will act as a Master) to a Raspberry pi 4 (which will act as a Slave) via the SDIO protocol.
Does Raspberry pi support this mode?
